# How to use Cordova Camera Picture in PDFMake?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building Ionic Cordova App in Angular. I have to create a PDF with the form values and pictures. I am using Cordova Camera to get the image which works fine.

Once I get the image, how should I use it in my PDFmake without converting to Base64? Base64 is extensive and breaks on older devices.

**Camera Get Picture**

```
  takePicture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 95,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
      targetWidth: 400,
      targetHeight: 400,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
      correctOrientation: true
    };
    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      const sourceDirectory = imageData.substring(0, imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      const sourceFileName = imageData.substring(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, imageData.length);
      this.selectedImage = this.webView.convertFileSrc(imageData);
      this.photos.push({
        image: this.selectedImage,
        rawImage: sourceFileName,
      });
      this.storage.set('photos', this.photos);
      console.log('Copying from : ' + sourceDirectory + sourceFileName);
      console.log('Copying to : ' + this.file.dataDirectory + sourceFileName);
      this.file.copyFile(sourceDirectory, sourceFileName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, sourceFileName).then(function(success) {
         const fileName = cordova.file.dataDirectory + sourceFileName;
         console.log(fileName);
      }, (error) => {
         console.dir(error);
      });
    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
     console.log('Camera issue:' + err);
    });
  }
```

With PDFmake, I am able to make the PDF with form values but pictures only show if I am using base64. I don't want to use base64.

I want to store the captured pictures in app and then use the local files.

Comment: when you capture image it save image on temporary path so please move it to other   directory and used that path.

Comment: I moved it to File Data Directory but no luck yet.

Comment: can you share some code ?

Answer (score 0):

PDFMake accepts Base64 and URI to display an image. If you don't want the B64 version, pass the URI of your picture to an [Image object](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/images/).